# machine learning algorithm that says which train data cause current decision

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, pattern-recognition

I need a learning model that when we test it with a data sample it says which train data cause the answer .
Is there anything that do this?
(I already know KNN will do this)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look for [generative models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model) 
 "It asks the question: based on generation assumptions, which category is most likely to generate this signal?"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very well worded question:

> Which train data cause the answer? I already know KNN will do this

KNN will tell you what the K nearest neighbors are, but it's not just those K training samples that *cause* the answer, it's also all the other training samples by being farther away.
The objective of machine learning is to generalize from the whole of the training dataset, so all samples in the training dataset (after outlier filtering, dataset reduction steps) *cause* the answer.

If your question is 'Which class of machine learning algorithms makes a decision by comparing a new instance to instances seen in the training data, and can list  the training examples which most strongly informed the decision?', the answer is: Instance based learning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance-based_learning
(e.g. KNN, kernel machines, RBF)